# Parsing into a complex type

Tags: f#, fparsec

I'm so new at F# and FParsec, I don't even want to embarrass myself by showing what I've got so far.

In the FParsec examples, every type in the ASTs (that I see) are type abbreviations for single values, lists, or tuples.

**What if I have a complex type which is supposed to hold, say, a parsed function name and its parameters?**

So, `f(a, b, c)` would be parsed to an object of type `PFunction` which has a string member `Name` and a `PParameter` list member `Parameters`.  How can I go from a parser which can match `f(a, b, c)` and `|>>` it into a `PFunction`?

All I seem to be able to do so far is create the composite parser, but not turn it into anything.  The Calculator example would be similar if it made an AST including a type like Term but instead it seems to me to be an interpreter rather than a parser, so there is no AST.  Besides, Term would probably just be a tuple of other type abbreviated components.

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't used FParsec, but in fsyacc you would typically model it as a discriminated union. E.g., `type Func = Func of string * Parameter list`

Comment: Thanks.  1) That's what I'm assuming Term would look like if Calc generated an AST - and I'm just as confused as to how to return such a tuple from a parser - , but 2) I'm under the impression that such types are not as friendly when imported into C# which is my motivation.

Comment: I think I need to use pipe2. But I need to be able to discard the parentheses, for example.  I could use pipe4, perhaps, and discard the two (second and fourth) parenthesis characters that are input to the pipe function, but what if there is more to discard?  Do I reduce head of time with `.>>` and `.<<`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
let pIdentifier o =
    let isIdentifierFirstChar c = isLetter c || c = '_'
    let isIdentifierChar c = isLetter c || isDigit c || c = '_'
    many1Satisfy2L isIdentifierFirstChar isIdentifierChar "identifier" <| o

let pParameterList p = 
    spaces >>. 
        pchar '(' >>. spaces >>. sepBy (spaces >>. p .>> spaces) (pchar ',') 
            .>> spaces .>> pchar ')'

type FunctionCall(Name: string, Parameters: string list) =
    member this.Name = Name
    member this.Parameters = Parameters

let pFunctionCall o= 
    pipe2 (pIdentifier) (pParameterList pIdentifier) (fun name parameters -> FunctionCall(name, parameters)) <|o
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a completely contrived but here's what I think it would look like the following, using pipe2 instead of |>>

```
type FunctionCall(Name: string, Parameters: string list) =
    member this.Name = Name
    member this.Parameters = Parameters

let pFunctionCall = 
    pipe2 (pIdentifier) (pstring "(" >>. pParameterList .>> pstring ")") (fun name parameters -> FunctionCall(name, parameters))
```

Answer (score 0):

The functional answer would be to use a discriminated union, as Daniel mentioned. FParsec also has a UserState that can be used like a state monad, so if you really want to parse directly into a complex type, you can use that. [1]

[1] http://cs.hubfs.net/topic/None/60071